# I'm getting an error when attempting to set up nginx on Heroku

Tags: heroku, heroku-nodejs

I'm getting an error when my dyno attempts to start nginx, on both heroku-16 and heroku-18:

> bin/start-nginx: No such file or directory

I used the [heroku-buildpack-multi](https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi) buildpack.

`.buildpacks` file:

> `"https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nginx.git"
>   "https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs.git"`

`Procfile`:

> `web: bin/start-nginx npm start`

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the latest versions of Heroku CLI support multiple buildpacks natively, and the `.buildpacks file is not used`, so all I had to do was use the command (from [here](https://github.com/ryandotsmith/nginx-buildpack/issues/68#issuecomment-353672493)):

`heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nginx.git`

to add the nginx buildpack.